# How to find the column number of those columns with single value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find the column number of columns with single value: here is my dataframe:

```
Cow_ID,Collar_label,BCS,Age_weeks,Height_cm,Weight_kg
cow1,aq5t,90,14,90,120
cow2,aq4r,92,14,92,118
cow3,aq2f,87,14,87,120
cow4,aq7u,81,14,81,118
cow5,aq9p,93,14,93,120
cow6,aq4m,89,14,89,120
cow7,aq1v,86,14,86,118
cow8,aq2c,92,14,92,120
cow9,aq5t,89,14,89,120
cow10,aq5x,88,14,88,118
```

and here is my code by which I can get the column name of the ones with single value:

```
df = read_csv(filename, header=0)
print("Data frame size: ", df.shape)
print("Data frame : ", df)

# get the number of unique values for each column
counts = df.nunique()


print("number of unique values within each column:")
print(counts)
 

print("column with single value: ", counts[counts ==1])
```

but I need column number to pop up automatically instead of column name.
Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the index of the series with single values:

```
counts[counts ==1].index[0]
>> 'Age_weeks'
```

A conditional gives a list of `True/False` matching to column numbers:

```
df.columns == 'Age_weeks'
>> array([False, False, False,  True, False, False])
```

And use `np.where` to get the index of `True` item, which equals to your column number:

```
np.where(df.columns == counts[counts ==1].index[0])
>>(array([3]),)
```

To get the number:

```
np.where(df.columns == counts[counts ==1].index[0])[0][0]
>> 3
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain to me how does this code works:np.where(df.columns == counts[counts ==1].index[0])[0][0]. I am beginner and in the learning process

Comment: So `counts[counts ==1]` is from the question code, returns a pandas.Series with one row because there is only one item with value 1 in "counts" Series. (btw, if you want to handle multiple items, you need to do an iteration here.) `.index[0]` returns the name of this row. `df.columns` contains all column names of df, so `==` gives a boolean list matching to columns. Finally, `np.where` returns index of `True` which is in fact df column number.

Comment: That's because of the type of output that `np.where` returns. It returns a tuple of two numpy arrays, each array contains indexes of a dimension. In our case the array of boolean is a single dimension. So we get a tuple of "numpy array" and "empty" : `(array([3]),)`. The first `[0]` picks first item of the tuple, and second `[0]` picks the number inside numpy array.

Comment: @Manakin this does not give the column number, it just shows column content. Can you correct that please? I want to try your code

Answer (score 0):

if you want the index of the column then create a dictionary with a key, value pair, the key being the index and the value being the column name.

```
enum = dict(enumerate(df.columns))

column_nums = {v : k for k,v in enum.items() if v in counts[counts ==1].index}

{'Age_weeks': 3}
```

---

```
print(enum)

{0: 'Cow_ID',
 1: 'Collar_label',
 2: 'BCS',
 3: 'Age_weeks',
 4: 'Height_cm',
 5: 'Weight_kg'}
```